# Collating results from multiple pytest runs

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I have a requirement to run the same set of test cases against different databases. The database is set up as part of a config variable in `conftest.py`, which is in turn controlled by an optional parameter:

```sh
> pytest --postgresql tests
```

I programmatically invoke pytest to run the same tests with multiple databases:

```py
for db in ['postgresql', 'sqlite']:
    print(f"Running tests for DB: {db}...")
    pytest.main([f"--{db}", "tests"])
```

This method of invocation works, but it prints the results of each test run separately.

I was wondering if there is a way to:

1. Collate these results so that the result would contain a summary of all tests
2. Supply the parameters and invoke the tests multiple times differently, which automatically outputs a summary result.

I really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of running the tests for each database separately, you could just run them in parametrized tests. One way is to pass all neded databases in the same parameter on the command line like this:

```py
dbs = ['postgresql', 'sqlite']
pytest.main([f"--databases={','.join(dbs)}", "tests"])
```

Register the option:

*conftest.py*

```py
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--databases", action="store")
```

And parametrize the tests with each database name:

```py
import pytest

@pytest.hookimpl
def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    if "database" in metafunc.fixturenames:
        databases = metafunc.config.option.databases
        if databases:
            metafunc.parametrize("database", databases.split(","))
        else:
            # handle default if no option is given
            metafunc.parametrize("database", ["postgresql"])


def test_database(database):
    print(database)
    ...
```

This would run the test consecutively for each database.
If you would rather use separate options for each database, you have to check them separately, something like:

```py
@pytest.hookimpl
def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    if "database" in metafunc.fixturenames:
        databases = []
        if metafunc.config.option.postgresql:
            databases.append("postgresql")
        if metafunc.config.option.mysql:
            databases.append("mysql")
        if databases:
            metafunc.parametrize("database", databases)
```

This assumes that it is ok to mix the tests for diffeerent databases.